# JS/POST/AJAX success - loosing other js functionalities on page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have such script that works ok but after success I cannot do anything with the js until refresh the page.

My code looks as follow:

```js
<script>
  $("#submit_comment").click(function() {
    
    var url = "{$sitepath}/comment.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#cform0").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {         
            $("#myHeader").load(location.href + " #myHeader > *", "");    
               }
             });
    
        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
</script>
```

It works if I change the

```
$("#myHeader").load(location.href + " #myHeader > *", "");
```

to:

```
$("#myHeader").load("#myHeader");
```

but then `myHeader` appears again in `myHeader` on page.
The question. Is there any possible to load the myHeader and keep the JS on site(sesion)?

Thanks for any suggestions.